# If fixed-point iteration has linear convergence, how can Newton's Method have quadratic convergence?

Tags: convergence-divergence, fixed-point-theorems, newton-raphson, rate-of-convergence

Newton's Method for finding the roots of a function can be considered a type of fixed point iteration of $g(x) = x - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$, since $f(k) = 0 \rightarrow g(k) = k$. But it is well-known that fixed point iteration has linear convergence while Newton's Method has quadratic convergence, given some assumptions on $f$ and $g$ such that $f'(k) \neq 0$. How is this possible? Shouldn't Newton's Method have the same rate of convergence in this case as fixed point iteration?

Comment: "it is well-known that fixed point iteration has linear convergence" [citation-needed]

Comment: Under assumptions of Banach fixed point theorem, the method is known to have *at least* linear convergence, but it does not contradict that more detailed analysis reveals, in fact, *at least* quadratic convergence for Newtons's method. Convergence analysis is always the worst case study.